# Spring OAuth2 uses wrong authentication details for a token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am having following configuration in Spring Security wiht OAuth2:

```
  @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
//@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class FVSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 
    @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
          .password("secret")
          .roles("USER", "ROLE1")
          .and()
        .withUser("admin")
          .password("password")
          .roles("ADMIN","USER");
  }

   @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .anonymous().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler())
        .and()
    .formLogin();
  }
```

Resource server configuraion:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) 
      throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("sampleClient")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit")
               .scopes("read")
               .autoApprove(true)
               .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30)
               .and()
               .withClient("user")
               .secret("secret")
               .scopes("read", "write")
               .autoApprove(true)
               .authorizedGrantTypes(
                "password","authorization_code", "refresh_token")
               .and()
               .withClient("admin")
               .secret("password")
               .scopes("read", "write", "custom")
               .autoApprove(true)
               .authorizedGrantTypes(
                "password","authorization_code", "refresh_token");
    }
```

And the following Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class OAuthTestController {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ROLE1') and #oauth2.hasScope('read')")
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/user/test1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testGETWithRole() {
        return  "[GET] Needs role ROLE1";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/admin/test1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testWithAdminRole() {
    return  "[GET] Needs Admin role";
}
```

And the resource server:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableResourceServer
 public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
}


@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
    anonymous().disable()
    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
    .and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
    .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

}

Basically I am expecting Spring to use OAuth2 for authentication and use spring security roles to allow resource access.
I generated and admin token and afterwards an user token. I am expecting when using admin token to be able to access /api/admin resource and when using user token to not be able.
I just noticed that the form login is not prompted always, so I suppose Spring remembers the authenticated user.

When I used the admin token I got access denied. When debugging in Spring sources I noticed that the authentication was an instance of UserNamePasswordAuthenticationPassword with the user details, not admin as expected. I suppose is because last time I used those credentials in login form. 
Is it a way to force spring to use credentials for corresponding token, or to force Spring show login form each time?

P.S. I use Postman to test the API.

Thanks.

Comment: where you have your resourceserver configuration? I can only see the authorization server configuration.

Comment: @bilak, I have updated the post with the resource server.